# Finding the Min Value for a Dynamic set of columns using a second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables.  My end goal is to get the Minimum value from a set of columns in Table 1.  The columns I choose in Table 1 may change, and are based on data found in Table 2.

Example: If today was "Monday", I would want Table 2 to select the columns to be used, and then use only those chosen columns in the Minimum Column Calculation in Table 1.

(I would want the Minimum value of "Col A" and "Col C" in Table 1)

I'm using Microsoft SQL.

**Table 1**

| # | Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Row 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |

**Table 2**

| Day | Column Name |
| --- | --- |
| Monday | Col A |
| Tuesday | Col B |
| Monday | Col C |
| Tuesday | Col D |

I have tried a bunch of terribly written SQL code and I'm too embarrassed to post it.  :)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's almost impossible understand what you want. I suggest you to share some sample data and expected output.

Comment: You should TAG the specific RDBMS you are expecting an answer for; presumably you would have elaborated if there were ever more or less than 4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of unions with "tagged" elements would get you there. This isn't necessarily a great road to go down though:

```
with data(Col, Tag) as (
    select ColA, 'Col A' from T union all
    select ColB, 'Col B' from T union all
    select ColC, 'Col C' from T union all
    select ColD, 'Col D' from T 
)
select min(Col) from data
where Tag in (
    select "Column 2" from Table2 where Day = <Today>
)
```

It might be beneficial to aggregate the columns inside the CTE as well so that you're then only grabbing four individual values rather than (logically) concatenating all the values together. You can play around and decide which works better with your indexes. Remember that SQL is declarative.